# How I can Change text of textarea using Htmlunit in Java?

Tags: java, htmlunit

How I can change the text in a textarea element?
I have the following code:

```
HtmlTextArea DescriptionOne = formulario.getTextAreaByName ("description");

DescriptionOne .setText ("Hi!");
```

But the form does not change this value.
And with other elements such as input type if I work

Comment: No, Java has a library called HtmlUnit that emulates a browser.

Comment: You need to be more specific. How do you know that textarea is not set? Are you perhaps trying to change content of area you see in your opened browser (like FireFox, Chrome, Opera)? If that so, you can't to it, HtmlUtil is meant to simulate simple browser itself, it is not to change other browsers content.

Comment: Because, I print the page by Console, and the TextArea is null

Comment: That is strange. Are you sure that you picked the right form? Maybe there are more forms with textarea with same name, in that case you would simply set wrong area. Consider posting example which will let us reproduce your problem: HTML of page you want to parse and [short but full code example](http://sscce.org/).